# Which DITA Element for Teaser Text

Tags: dita

Does anyone know if there is an element in DITA, to specify Text as teaser text?
I will use the teaser text for search engine optimization.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "teaser text" you mean text that appears on a results page when the item has been retrieved as part of a search. And I assume that you are transforming your DITA XML into HTML.

There is no DITA element specifically for teaser text, but `<shortdesc>` would probably be a good choice. You could also get fancier and do a specialization to create your own element for this, and name it something like `<teasertext>`. A specialization like that is a lot more work though.

If you want the teaser text for SEO purposes, you will probably have to adjust the DITA Open Toolkit to put the `<shortdesc>` content in an HTML `<meta>` tag (assuming you use the DITA OT).